# How do I PUT to the github API using angularjs $http service

Tags: angularjs, github

- *I wish follow user usign the github api , my application built with
  angulajs , using the $http service*

Comment: Or use https://github.com/sahat/satellizer?

Comment: please show us what have you done ?

Comment: $http.put('https://api.github.com/user/following/JakeWharton',
            {
             headers : {
             'Content-Type':'application/json',
             'Authorization': 'token %s' % 'a4abd33e7823ae6ae21ec78adb47695dc92d0255',
             }
             }
            )
        .then(function(data){
            console.log('data' + data)

        }).catch(function(er){
            console.log('err' + JSON.stringify(er))
        })